# Are there other locations than \data\logs to look into for clues on "An error occured" message?

Tags: placeholders

I'm on page 59 of APress Phil Wicklund's "Professional Sitecore 8 Development".

I'm trying to add my Rendering to the "main" Placeholder.

Experience Editor => click inside the "Main" Placeholder => "Add here" => "Select Rendering" => "Select" .

"Message from Webpage"  "an error occurred".

I've scoured all the logs from /data/logs/ but without seeing anything related.

Question: are there other places I need to look into, for more clues?

Thank you,

Comment: I don’t think so. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hi Artsem, thanks, you just got me closer! 

"Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server"

Comment: Does your component have at least 1 html tag (even if no datasource is selected and if in Experience Editor mode)?

Comment: Yes, it's the book very minimal:

<div>
    @Html.Sitecore().Field(“Additional Text”)
</div>

Comment: I see it's a known issue there:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/867739

Comment: but we are 8.1 so the issue has normally been fixed. It did work at some point in previous attempts. I will try to do a brand new set of items (Layout, Template, Standard_Values, Placeholder, View Rendering, Content) with new names. I suspect that duplication in naming of the items, could be a reason.

Comment: The error message you wrote makes difficult to understand the error. Maybe, you should enable the Full Error Message, it would help you to identify the piece of the code that has an error

Did you enable custom errors?

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  ...
  </system.web>

Comment: Yes here it is:  
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/Error">  Thanks Jose, actually it's a JavaScript error, front-end, and so, with the debugging mode in IE, I could get this more specific: "Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server"

Answer (score 0):

You for sure have it going into the main placeholder? Do you have any renderings that do not have a placeholder specified?

What version of Sitecore are you running? Per the link @CoeuerDusite provided, it is a known issue:

```
To address the issue, apply one of the solutions below:
Always specify placeholder name for all presentation elements.
Upgrade website to Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150427 (Update-3) or newer, where this issue has been fixed.
Apply the patch as described below:
Put an Sitecore.Support.380995.v*.dll assembly into the \bin folder;
Put Siteocre.Support.380995.v*.config file into the \App_Config\Include folder.
Appropriate files can be retrieved from an archive, depending on the Sitecore version:
Sitecore 6.5 - 6.6: Sitecore.Support.380995.v1.zip - https://kb.sitecore.net/~/media/2C9A39977D8349EEB378F89245DC6D61.ashx?la=en
Sitecore 7.0 - 7.5: Sitecore.Support.380995.v2.zip - https://kb.sitecore.net/~/media/AE61B2778ACC4C108872F5F63519A67E.ashx?la=en
Sitecore 8.0: Sitecore.Support.380995.v3.zip - https://kb.sitecore.net/~/media/92301E04A678428CA7D13354B5F2E8FA.ashx?la=en
```

Comment: Yes the main placeholder, and I've just trying specifying the main placeholder in the (View) Rendering, although that seems to make for tight coupling: doesn't it mean that now this Rendering cannot be used elsewhere than in this one Placeholder? 
In Phil Wicklund's book "Professional Sitecore 8 Development" from Apress, there wasn't instructions for doing this. Re-re-checking...

Comment: You are correct, that if you are specifying the placeholder in the rendering you are tightly coupling. Typically, you will place it in the placeholder via the Presentation Details.